# Using Compare() method of the IComparer Interface

Tags: c#

Could anyone point out the error in my code.
I want to display the fuctionality of the 'Compare()' of the IComparer interface in c#.
Following are my 2 classes that I'm trying to use..

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DayFive
{
    class Employee
{
    public int id;
    public String name;

    public Employee(int _id,String _name)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Rishabh");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Shubham");
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "Akshay");

        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        al.Add(e1);
        al.Add(e2);
        al.Add(e3);

        //default
        al.Sort();

        IComparer<Employee> c = new MyCompare();
        al.Sort(c);
    }
}
}
```

and,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DayFive
{
class MyCompare : IComparer<Employee>
{
    public int Compare(Employee a,Employee b)
    {
        if (a.name.CompareTo(b.name) < 0)
            return -1;
        if (a.name.Equals(b.name))
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }


}
}
```

The error is coming while using the Sort() of the arrayList when object of the MyComparer class is passed in it as its parameter.

The errors are as follows ..

**Error 1   The best overloaded method match for                                          'System.Collections.ArrayList.Sort(System.Collections.IComparer)' has some             invalid arguments  c:\users\rkash4\documents\visual studio             2013\Projects\DayFive\DayFive\Program.cs    39  13  DayFive**

**Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from             'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer' to         'System.Collections.IComparer'  c:\users\rkash4\documents\visual studio                                             2013\Projects\DayFive\DayFive\Program.cs    39  21  DayFive**

Comment: Care to share what the error actually says?

Comment: `ArrayList` isn't generic so you just need an `IComparer`. If you use `List<Employee>` instead of `ArrayList` then your current comparer works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` isn't generic so you just need an `IComparer`. If you use `List<Employee>` instead of `ArrayList` then your current comparer works fine.

Try this:

```
    Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Rishabh");
    Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Shubham");
    Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "Akshay");

    List<Employee> al = new List<Employee>();
    al.Add(e1);
    al.Add(e2);
    al.Add(e3);

    IComparer<Employee> c = new MyCompare();
    al.Sort(c);
```

You should **not** use `ArrayList` anyway - it's so 2001.

Comment: Thanks, that removed the errors just fine.
However, it is displaying the following exception ..

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Failed to compare two elements in the array**.

Comment: @iamrkcheers - The default sort doesn't work now. Just take that out. Otherwise your class `Employee` would need to implement `IComparable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. that did the job !